# Can admin on rest write controller logic with fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

On an `<EditView />` I am using `<ReferenceArrayField />` to display an edit form of checkbox.

I need to fill the form with the data, but the checkbox list is so far implemented using the response entities from the `ReferenceArrayField`.

1. I have an the `user` entity fetched by the `<EditView/>`
2. In `<EditView/>` I am fetching related data using `
3. I write a custom grid using the `<ReferenceArrayField />` data
4. **I want to fill** the `checked` props of my checkbox **depending on values** present in `user`.

This would be some trivial controller logic for the UI but I can't find how to do it.

So far I am only able to have one `record` by scope which means that every data displayed on the UI would be from a single entity and no controller logic can be written in between.

### Use case

```
const CheckboxGrid = ({ ids, data, basePath }) => (
  <div style={{ margin: '1em' }}>
    {ids.map(id =>
      <div key={id}>
        <h2><TextField record={data[id]} source="description" /></h2>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="authority[]" disabled checked={true} />{' '}
          <TextField record={data[id]} source="role.description" />
        </label>
        {data[id].siteFunctionList.map((siteFunction) => (
          <div key={siteFunction.description} className="pl-3">
            <h3><TextField record={siteFunction} source="description" disabled /></h3>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="authority[]" disabled />{' '}
              <TextField record={siteFunction} source="role.description" />
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);

CheckboxGrid.defaultProps = {
  data: {},
  ids: [],
};


export class AuthorityList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const resourceName = 'users';
    const resourceId = this.props.match.params.id;
    return (
      <Edit {...this.props} resource={resourceName} id={resourceId}>
        <SimpleForm>
          <ReferenceArrayField reference="siteServices" source="siteServiceIdList">
            <CheckboxGrid />
          </ReferenceArrayField>
        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
    );
  }
}
```

The user have a list of values that would match some of the values present in `data`.

### Fact

- I do not have access to the `<Edit .../>` record in the scope of checkbox grid.
- I have seen that there is in `redux` a `form['record-form'].values` where the entity is store so I could access it with custom selectors:

EX:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  record: makeSelectFormRecordFormValues(),
});
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps);
const CheckboxGridConnect = compose(
  withConnect,
)(CheckboxGrid);
```

- There is also a store for each resources declared in admin on rest. It store the entities fetched with `<ReferenceArrayField />` but I don't see these stores scalable in case we use more than one  `<ReferenceArrayField />` for the same resource.

Should I directly pick in the store and inject my self the entities ?

Comment: Can you please explain what controller logic is?

Comment: So what I understand is that there are multiple elements in your form some of which might be fetched using ReferenceArray etc and you will need to edit those values but cannot do so in a request because you can only edit the current record. Is this your challenge? If yes then you can try and create multiple forms on the same page each of which edit their respective fields. They are all hooked to the same save button. I personally just edited my API to send all relevant related data in an array and then a custom method that updated all related fields if it detected any changes.

Comment: It was a lot of work. I even had to write my own custom ReferenceArray field. But in the end I think that was a faster solution for me.

Comment: `Is this your challenge? `: The element fetched in ReferenceArrayField is used to draw and display the form of checkbox. The entity fetched by the edit view is the one that own the values that will determine if the checkbox are checked or not. (I have edited the question in case it was badly explained). `I even had to write my own custom ReferenceArray field`  
What you have wrote is it scalable and can it be shared ? May I see an example of code ?

Comment: Don't think it was scalable. Mega hacky but will share.

Comment: my mistake. It wasnt ReferenceInput. But a  customSelect input

Comment: You can simply pass the record to checkBoxGrid as some custom prop such as <CheckboxGrid outerRecord={record} /> you can now access it as outerRecord inside your component and check its values to determine if a field is displayed as checked by default or not

Comment: It's the problem, `record` doesn't exist as a variable. If you wanted to read `record.name`  You can access it using a `<TextField source="name" />` but you can't access the record directly.

Comment: Yes you can access the record. It is passed as this.props.record to the Edit component. You can then pass it to your component as another prop which you can name outerData or something

Answer (score 0):

Please find below my hacky code for SelectInput. I have made this to basically edit an array of values. The API detects any changes in the array of values and updates the references accordingly. Below is a copy paste job from the AOR core and then some modifications for my use case.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import get from 'lodash.get';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';


export class CustomSelectInput extends Component {
    /*
     * Using state to bypass a redux-form comparison but which prevents re-rendering
     * @see https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2456
     */
    state = {
        value: this.props.fields.get(this.props.selectionOrder) ? this.props.fields.get(this.props.selectionOrder) : null //selectionOrder is a prop I am passing to the component manually. It is very specific to my use case
    }

    handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.props.fields.remove(this.props.selectionOrder) //using redux-form fields methods to remove items and adding new ones. SelectionOrder now becomes an unfortunate hard coding of the particular value this selectInput is supposed to edit in the array of values
        this.props.fields.push(value);
        this.setState({ value });
    }

    renderMenuItem = (choice) => {
        const {
            optionText,
            optionValue,
        } = this.props;
        const choiceName = React.isValidElement(optionText) ? // eslint-disable-line no-nested-ternary
            React.cloneElement(optionText, { record: choice }) :
            (typeof optionText === 'function' ?
                optionText(choice) :
                get(choice, optionText)
            );
        return (
            <MenuItem
                key={get(choice, optionValue)}
                primaryText={choiceName}
                value={choice.name}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const {
            allowEmpty,
            choices,
            elStyle,
            input,
            isRequired,
            label,
            meta: { touched, error },
            options,
            resource,
            source,
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <SelectField
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                autoWidth
                style={elStyle}
                errorText={touched && error}
                {...options}
            >
                {allowEmpty &&
                    <MenuItem value={null} primaryText="" />
                }
                {choices.map(this.renderMenuItem)}
            </SelectField>
        );
    }
}

CustomSelectInput.propTypes = {
    addField: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    allowEmpty: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    choices: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    elStyle: PropTypes.object,
    input: PropTypes.object,
    isRequired: PropTypes.bool,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    meta: PropTypes.object,
    options: PropTypes.object,
    optionText: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
        PropTypes.element,
    ]).isRequired,
    optionValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    resource: PropTypes.string,
    source: PropTypes.string
};

CustomSelectInput.defaultProps = {
    addField: true,
    allowEmpty: false,
    choices: [],
    options: {},
    optionText: 'name',
    optionValue: 'id'
};

export default CustomSelectInput
```